# is there any way to validate Textfield in bottomsheet?

Tags: flutter, validation, dart, textfield, bottom-sheet

I want to validate my textfield(not textFormField) which is in bottomsheet, if textfield is empty it should shows error when I pressed the save button.
I used below code the problem with the code is it shows error only when I press on save button and should close the bottomsheet  and when I open bottomsheet then it will show error.
Is there any way to validate the textfield on pressing save button and without closing the bottomsheet.
Thanks in advance.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: AddAddress()));



class AddNotes extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  AddAddressState createState() => AddAddressState();
}

class AddAddressState extends State<AddAddress> {

  final _text = TextEditingController();
  bool _validate = false;

  @override
  void dispose(){
    _text.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  bottomSheet() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.85,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.transparent,
              ),
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 0),
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: const Radius.circular(10.0),
                        topRight: const Radius.circular(10.0))),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [


                    Text("Address",
                        textScaleFactor: 1.3,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontFamily: 'SFProDisplay',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                            letterSpacing: 0.45),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center),

                    Container(
                        height: 215,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0x7feff1f5),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(17, 16, 17, 25),
                        child: new ConstrainedBox(
                          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200.0),
                          child: new Scrollbar(
                            child: new SingleChildScrollView(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                              reverse: true,
                              child: SizedBox(
                                height: 175.0,
                                child: new TextField(

                                  controller: _text,

                                  maxLines: 100,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: "Address",
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0x00FFa6a9af),
                                    ),
                                    border: InputBorder.none,

                                    errorText: _validate ? 'Notes can\'t be Empty' : null,

                                  ),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    height: 1.4,
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontFamily: 'regular',
                                    letterSpacing: 0.35,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )),

                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 188, 0),
                      child:ElevatedButton(
                        child: Text('Save'),
                        onPressed: (){
                          setState(() {
                            _text.text.isEmpty ? _validate = true : _validate = false;
                          });
                        },
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: Colors.redAccent,
                          onPrimary: Colors.white,
                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'regular',
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                          ),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                          ),),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ));
        });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        title: Text(
          "",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontFamily: "regular"),
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        ),
        centerTitle: false,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            bottomSheet();
          },
          child: Text("AddAddress"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I checked it is because it doesn't properly rebuild so you have to close it then open it so the state that is change would effect.

I have added a changeNotifier class to keep the state and notify its listeners using provider package you can take look at it:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: AddAddress()));


class AddAddress extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  AddAddressState createState() => AddAddressState();
}

class AddAddressState extends State<AddAddress> {

  

  @override
  void dispose(){
    super.dispose();
  }

  bottomSheet() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => CustomProvider(),child: CustomTextField());
        });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        title: Text(
          "",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontFamily: "regular"),
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        ),
        centerTitle: false,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            bottomSheet();
          },
          child: Text("AddAddress"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.85,
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 0),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: const Radius.circular(10.0),
                  topRight: const Radius.circular(10.0))),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [


              Text("Address",
                  textScaleFactor: 1.3,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontFamily: 'SFProDisplay',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                      letterSpacing: 0.45),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center),

              Container(
                  height: 215,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0x7feff1f5),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(17, 16, 17, 25),
                  child: new ConstrainedBox(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200.0),
                    child: new Scrollbar(
                      child: new SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        reverse: true,
                        child: Consumer<CustomProvider>(
                          builder: (context, item, child) => SizedBox(
                            height: 175.0,
                            child: new TextField(

                              controller: Provider.of<CustomProvider>(context, listen: false).text,

                              maxLines: 100,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "Address",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0x00FFa6a9af),
                                ),
                                border: InputBorder.none,

                                errorText: item.validate ? 'Notes can\'t be Empty' : null,

                              ),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                height: 1.4,
                                fontSize: 16,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontFamily: 'regular',
                                letterSpacing: 0.35,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )),

              Container(
                height: 50,
                color: Colors.transparent,
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 188, 0),
                child:ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text('Save'),
                  onPressed: (){
                    Provider.of<CustomProvider>(context, listen: false).checkValidation();
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Colors.redAccent,
                    onPrimary: Colors.white,
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'regular',
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                    ),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                    ),),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class CustomProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  final text = TextEditingController();
  bool validate = false;
  
  void checkValidation(){
    if(text.text.isEmpty){
      validate = true;
    }else{
      validate = false;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hai @Mohammad could you help me for my another question [New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69491598/how-to-customize-the-horizontal-time-picker-in-flutter)