# How to stop selecting multiple containers in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview, flutter-container

Hi folks I am new to flutter and trying to design a horizontal time picker using list builder but am unable to select only one container it allowing me to select multiple containers but I want only one to select, below I attached code please help to select only one container.I want to pick only one time container to select time range and print below from and to time. Thanks in Advance.
[image: screenshot my UI]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "custom time picker horizontal",
      home: TimePickerScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class TimePickerScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _TimePickerScreenState createState() => _TimePickerScreenState();
}

class _TimePickerScreenState extends State<TimePickerScreen> {
  String selectedFromTime = " ";
  List<String> fromTimeList = ["0:00", "0:30", "1:00", "1:30", "2:00", "2:30", "3:00", "3:30", "4:00", "4:30", "5:00", "5:30", "6:00", "6:30"];
  List<bool> fromTimeListSelect =[false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,];

  String selectedToTime =" ";
  List<String> toTimeList = ["0:00", "0:30", "1:00", "1:30", "2:00", "2:30", "3:00", "3:30", "4:00", "4:30", "5:00", "5:30", "6:00", "6:30"];
  List<bool> toTimeListSelect =[false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('custom time picker horizontal'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Divider(),
          fromTime(),
          Divider(),
          toTime(),
          Text('From : $selectedFromTime To : $selectedToTime'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget fromTime(){
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: fromTimeList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
            return GestureDetector(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                child: Center(
                    child: Text(fromTimeList[index],
                      style: TextStyle(color: fromTimeListSelect[index] ? Colors.white : Colors.black ,fontSize: 16),)),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: fromTimeListSelect[index] ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              onTap: (){
                //isSelectedC = !isSelectedC;
                fromTimeListSelect[index] = !fromTimeListSelect[index];
                fromTimeListSelect[index] == true ? selectedFromTime =fromTimeList[index] : selectedFromTime= ' ';
                print(fromTimeListSelect[index]);
                print(fromTimeList[index]);
                setState(() {

                });
              },
            );

          },),
    );
  }

  Widget toTime(){
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: fromTimeList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
          return GestureDetector(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
              child: Center(
                  child: Text(toTimeList[index],
                    style: TextStyle(color: toTimeListSelect[index] ? Colors.white : Colors.black ,fontSize: 16),)),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: toTimeListSelect[index] ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            onTap: (){
              //isSelectedC = !isSelectedC;
              toTimeListSelect[index] = !toTimeListSelect[index];
              toTimeListSelect[index] == true ? selectedToTime =toTimeList[index] : selectedToTime= ' ';
              print(toTimeListSelect[index]);
              print(toTimeList[index]);
              setState(() {

              });
            },
          );

        },),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check, is it working for you?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "custom time picker horizontal",
      home: TimePickerScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class TimePickerScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _TimePickerScreenState createState() => _TimePickerScreenState();
}

class _TimePickerScreenState extends State<TimePickerScreen> {
  String selectedFromTime = " ";
  List<String> fromTimeList = ["0:00", "0:30", "1:00", "1:30", "2:00", "2:30", "3:00", "3:30", "4:00", "4:30", "5:00", "5:30", "6:00", "6:30"];
  List<bool> fromTimeListSelect =[false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,];

  String selectedToTime =" ";
  List<String> toTimeList = ["0:00", "0:30", "1:00", "1:30", "2:00", "2:30", "3:00", "3:30", "4:00", "4:30", "5:00", "5:30", "6:00", "6:30"];
  List<bool> toTimeListSelect =[false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('custom time picker horizontal'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Divider(),
          fromTime(),
          Divider(),
          toTime(),
          Text('From : $selectedFromTime To : $selectedToTime'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget fromTime(){
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: fromTimeList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
          return GestureDetector(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
              child: Center(
                  child: Text(fromTimeList[index],
                    style: TextStyle(color: fromTimeListSelect[index] ? Colors.white : Colors.black ,fontSize: 16),)),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: fromTimeListSelect[index] ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            onTap: (){
              //isSelectedC = !isSelectedC;

              setState(() { // here the update need

                for(int i=0; i< fromTimeListSelect.length;i++){
                  fromTimeListSelect[i] = false;
                }
                print(fromTimeListSelect);
                fromTimeListSelect[index] = !fromTimeListSelect[index];
                fromTimeListSelect[index] == true ? selectedFromTime =fromTimeList[index] : selectedFromTime= ' ';
                print(fromTimeListSelect);
              });
            },
          );

        },),
    );
  }

  Widget toTime(){
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: fromTimeList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
          return GestureDetector(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
              child: Center(
                  child: Text(toTimeList[index],
                    style: TextStyle(color: toTimeListSelect[index] ? Colors.white : Colors.black ,fontSize: 16),)),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: toTimeListSelect[index] ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            onTap: (){
              //isSelectedC = !isSelectedC;
              toTimeListSelect[index] = !toTimeListSelect[index];
              toTimeListSelect[index] == true ? selectedToTime =toTimeList[index] : selectedToTime= ' ';
              print(toTimeListSelect[index]);
              print(toTimeList[index]);
              setState(() { // here the update need
                for(int i=0; i< toTimeListSelect.length;i++){
                  toTimeListSelect[i] = false;
                }
                toTimeListSelect[index] = !toTimeListSelect[index];
                toTimeListSelect[index] == true ? selectedToTime =toTimeList[index] : selectedToTime= ' ';
                print(toTimeListSelect[index]);
                print(toTimeList[index]);
              });
            },
          );

        },),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, @jahidul I want to remember selected items when I reopen the screen, how can I do that,could you explain it?

Comment: Hey @jahidul I posed another question can you please go through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69999701/how-to-customize-the-checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-rang-slider-in-flutters). Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Add this `fromTimeListSelect` in  `setState`

```
onTap: (){
                    //isSelectedC = !isSelectedC;
                    fromTimeListSelect[index] = !fromTimeListSelect[index];
                    fromTimeListSelect[index] == true ? selectedFromTime =fromTimeList[index] : selectedFromTime= ' ';
                    print(fromTimeListSelect[index]);
                    print(fromTimeList[index]);
                    setState(() {
                       fromTimeListSelect; //just add this line
                    });
                  }
```